# Insert salutation depending on the number of characters

Tags: sql, impala

Where salutation is >15 characters, the word ‘Hi’ is to be inserted in the  field

thought about using a regex function, but not sure how to implement this

when regexp_like(salutation, > '^[0-9]{15}$') then 'Hi'

```
MR Nigel Humphreys  -> "hi"
Ms Montjoy          ->  "Ms Montjoy"
Mr Fitz-Lloyd Smith -> "hi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `length()` and `case`?

```
select (case when length(salutation) > 15 then 'hi'
             else salutation
        end) as new_salutation
```

If you want to actually overwrite the field, you need an update:

```
update t
    set salutation = 'hi'
    where length(salutation) > 15;
```